# How do i loop an ajax request (using jquery) and jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

```
<script>

//when page is ready do the following
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //set interval of refresh
    setInterval(doAjaxMethod, 1000);

});

function doAjaxMethod(id)
{ 
     $.ajax({
        url: "getStatus/"+id,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json)
        {
            $('#ajaxStatus').html(json.status);
        }    
});
</script>

<%
   //How can I do something like this

    int n = object.size();

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
         doAjaxMethod(object.getId());
    } 
%>

<div id=ajaxStatus> status updates here </div>
```

Comment: Do you want the AJAX event to fire every few seconds or what? Please clarify your question in this respect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not mix calling javascript from within scriplets.  Instead, manage the loop in javascript.  If you describe more of what you are trying to do, I can be more specific.  It seems you have an container object available on the jsp, and you need to loop thru to get the statuses of what is in the container.  Instead of passing that object to the jsp, why don't you create an endpoint that the javascript on the jsp can invoke in ajax to get ALL the data you need.

Answer (score 2):

One approach you can do is add a them to a list like object with a css class and trigger the ajax method on it `onLoad`.
Here is some untested (and probably uncompiled)

```
<%
   //How can I do something like this

    int n = object.size();

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
         out.println("<li class='abcd' id ='<%=object.getId()%>'>" +object.getId() +"</li>");
    } 
%>
```

and then in javascript on pageload

```
$(function(){
    $('.abc').each(i, v){
                doAjaxMethod($(v).attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming that `objArray` is an array):

```
$.each(objArray, function(i, obj) {
       doAjaxMethod(obj.getId());
});
```

It will iterate your array and `obj` is each of the items.
Hope it helps.